# JavaScript cannot calling to Android

Tags: javascript, android

### This is html code.

```
<button class="rechangeMember">
        Recharge
    </button>
<script src="http://121.42.9.33:8080/statics/common/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.rechangeMember').click(function(){
            if(typeof myObj != 'undefined')
            {
                myObj.rechargeMember();
            }
            else
            {
                rechargeMember();
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

#### Then I want calling this button in Android, code below

```
member_level_show.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    member_level_show.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    member_level_show.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    member_level_show.addJavascriptInterface(new Recharge(), "rechargeMember");
    member_level_show.loadUrl(Constants.URL_MEMBER_LEVEL + CurrentUserBean.getCurrentUser().getToken());
```

### Recharge class

```
class Recharge{
    @JavascriptInterface
    private void rechargeMember() {
        log("recharge");
    }
}
```

### then I click this button in webview, logcat is

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: rechargeMember is not defined"
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Android, but should rechargeMember be public instead of private since it gets accessed from the outside?

Comment: @Bemmu Thank you for your answer, I have changed rechageMember to public but the log also changed to "Uncaught TypeError: rechargeMember is not a function".

Comment: OK, I hope someone else can help you :)

Comment: @Bemmu Thank you very much!  I've solved my problem already.

Answer (score 1):

#### My code is error.

```
class Recharge{
    @JavascriptInterface
    private void rechargeMember() {
        log("recharge");
    }
}
```

#### should be changed to

```
  class Recharge{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void rechargeMember() {
        log("recharge");
    }
}
```

#### private can't be called outside, thank's for @Bemmu's comment.Second error is :

```
 member_level_show.addJavascriptInterface(new Recharge(), "rechargeMember");
```

#### "rechargeMember" should be "myObj", JavaScript code is:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.rechangeMember').click(function(){
        if(typeof myObj != 'undefined')
        {
            myObj.rechargeMember();
        }
        else
        {
            rechargeMember();
        }
    });
})
```

#### So Android function is called.

Answer (score 0):

The name you specify in `addJavaScriptInterface()` becomes the name of the object. So you have to use

```
rechargeMember.rechargeMember();
```